# Second Generation Beta Package Creation is failing in Github Action

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, git, cicd, github-actions

I'm trying to create a 2nd Gen package using Github Action (workflow dispatch Action). After I deployed and run the workflow it gave me an error while uploading the new package:
[image]

The error is on the "Application metadata". It seems that there is a profile that is unseen by the packaging process.

On the other hand I tried to create a new package as usual from the terminal using this command:

```
sfdx force:package:version:create -p "Package Name" -x -c -w 240 -f config/project-scratch-def.json
```

and it worked fine (in the github action I'm using exactly the same command line).

Only while running the github action it gave me this error. It could be due to the OS that I'm running the action in (`runs-on: ubuntu-latest`)?

Comment: Are you trying to create a patch (i.e. the last segment of the version number is non-zero)? If so, have you had Salesforce Support enable patching? Without this enabled you can receive misleading errors when trying to create patch release versions.

Comment: @PhilW patching yes is enabled on my devhub, Im creating another beta for the same version and not a new patch version.
The problem im facing is only in the github action and not everywere, the package uploaded successfully on the terminal in the vsCode but not in the github action